# Create Jar for a specific file in a project using ant

Tags: java, ant, build

I compiled all the java files using ant and stored the class files in a folder.
I want to make jar for a specific class file form the output folder(compiled).
How can i done this.
NOTE:The class file depends another classes in the project

Comment: you can specify path of all files which you want to use for JAR.

Comment: yes. @tim has answered in correct way, follow the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ant` [Jar Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) with a nested [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) that specifies only the file(s) you wish to include in the jar file.

Something like:

```
<jar jarfile="pinky.jar">
  <fileset dir="build/classes" >
    <include name="com/example/Brain.class" />
  </fileset>
</jar>
```